# unity change text label

Tags: c#, text, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and I have a bewbie question:
on my start screen I have a text object, and I want that when the scene is loaded, to change the value of this text label (for example for best score to load).

so I want to do something like this:

`GetComponent<GUIText>().text = "Best: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore", 0);`

But, how do I call this script when the scene is loaded? how do I call the right gui text named "Best" text?

thank you

EDIT: I will try to clarify my self and make it more general question: how do I execute code in unity, when the game loads? which object do I need to create for example, that right when the main screen of the game loads, it will also generate some code? Awake()? where exactly do I implement this awake method?

Comment: (1) open unity, click "Add Canvas" (tip, select "scale with screen size" - you always want that).    (2) click "Add Text" (or if you like Button, Slider, etc etc).  You're done.  You can't use the ancient "gui" system - it is deprecated. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, how do I call this script when the scene is loaded? how do I call
>   the right gui text named "Best" text?

Not sure what your problem is because your code is correct. It looks like you are looking for a way to find a GameOBject called "Best" then access the `GUIText` component attached to it.

If this is what you want, then you need to use `GameObject.Find("Best")` to find it then use `GetComponent<GUIText>()` on that GameObject you found to get the `GUIText` component that is attached to that GameObject.

```
GUIText bestScore;

void Start()
{
    //Find the GameObject named Best in the scene
    GameObject scoreGameObject = GameObject.Find("Best");

    //Get the GUIText Component attached to that GameObject named Best
    bestScore = scoreGameObject.GetComponent<GUIText>();

    //Load score 
    bestScore.text = "Best: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore", 0);
}
```

Comment: thank you, this is indeed what I was looking for. this directs me to the second question: how can I retrieve the phone number, when the user opens the game? with android studio I know, I just use the TelephonyManager object and uses the getSystemService methods, but in unity I hvae no idea... any help?

Comment: @danijinji Why would you want a user's phone number in a game app? Anyways, you have to write a plugin for that. You must know how to do it in Java then convert the Java code into a plugin and call it from C#. That's it. You can Google how to make Unity Android plugin and many result will come out.

Comment: hi I want to do it for practicing. I know how to do it in java anroid studio, can you be more specific please on what should I look in google in order to make this plugin or for example read contacts plugin?

Comment: @danijinji it's not someething I can write here. Sinceyou can do it in Android , here is how to make a plugin for Android or how to call java function from C#(Unity) http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2015/04/android-plugin-unity-android-studio.html